# Add custom links to tab in user module drupal

Tags: drupal, user-interface, drupal-7

I want to add some links to the tab in user modue in drupal.
Now when I go to /user on my site it shows “view” and “edit” links in tabs. And I'd liek to add some pages to this tab.
How do I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This might help. Im not sure if you can add tabs with tab tamer, but I know you can remove tabs.

http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer

Answer (score 0):

**This answer only applies if you are going to add a new tab for a Views page.** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248009/drupal-7-views-filter-by-owner

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248009/drupal-7-views-filter-by-owner
You'll need to use "User ID from URL" (I just answered this question).
Add a new "page" display.
In second pane of the View, under menu settings, add new "menu tab" and give it a name. you can forget the parent menu tree.
In page's url, enter something like `user/%/posts` where "posts" is anything you want. 
Save.